# $inc only if a new element was added to a set

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have an observer that waits for an object to change, then adds that job to a queue. This will fire whenever something has been added to a collection.

```
this.upsert({
  count: { $lt: this.config.limit }
}, {
  $setOnInsert: {
    queue: [],
    count: 0
  },
  $addToSet: {
    queue: doc._id
  },
  $inc: { count: 1 }  // herein lie the problem.
});
```

However, I am facing a problem where `count` will increment without anything technically being *added* to the set.

Is there a way to increment only if an element was added to the set in a single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by gating your update with another conditional term to check that `doc._id` isn't in the `queue` array yet.

```
this.upsert({
  count: { $lt: this.config.limit },
  queue: { $ne: doc._id }
}, {
  $setOnInsert: {
    queue: [],
    count: 0
  },
  $push: { // Can use $push instead of $addToSet now
    queue: doc._id
  },
  $inc: { count: 1 }
});
```

It's basically a DIY `$addToSet` that gives you more control.

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you sir

Comment: Nicely Done! The additional conditional term was a great idea.

Comment: Actually there is only one problem with this solution: if I try to push the same id, it will make a new document. Is there a way to have it just update its entry?